# como puedo binarizar una imagen png evitando los pixeles transparentes en python?

Tags: python

estoy intentando binarizar una imagen png, pero los pixeles transparentes se me vuelven blancos y necesito que se mantengan transparentes, adjunto unas imágenes de ejemplo y el código que estoy utilizando

[image: imagen]
[image: imagen1]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imgGris = cv2.imread("imagen.png")

umbral= 20

mascara = np.uint8((imgGris>umbral)*255)
cv2.imwrite("imagen1.png",mascara)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás leyendo la imagen en escala de grises, desde allí pierdes la trasparencia.

Leer la imagen con este código soluciona el problema, ya lee los 4 canales RGBA:

```py
imgGris = cv2.imread("imagen.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Ayuda de [How to load png images with 4 channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547458/13636459)